# Workflow migrations phalcon

Tags: php, migration, phalcon

Time ago I worked with yii framework.
In yii framework with yiic shell I make migration file and write actions for db: create table, alter table, create index and any actions with another (no db). 
But in phalcon I don't see this. Yeah, I know about migrations, but what is it?

I make migration for my db with one table;
If I have empty db and use "phalcon migration run" then I have "table %name_table% don't exists"

And how I can use this for normal migrations?

And where phalcon save information about used migrations? Or every time start from 1.0.0 migration?

Comment: This is a bug and it was fixed in the devtools repo

Comment: I confirm ↑, when running ``phalcon migration run`` and having an empty db, calling ``$this->morphTable()`` on ``up()`` function of migration class actually creates the table. "PS: trying Phalcon DevTools (2.0.0 BETA 3)"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DevTools 3.1.2, run the following command to learn more about migration options in Phalcon 3

`phalcon migration --help`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to dump one first - `phalcon gen-migration`

Try reading the full page and watching the tutorial video for them - http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/migrations.html

Comment: It's don't work how in video.

I have 2 tables and save dump.sql and make first migrations.
Then I make test table and add field to first table and make 1.0.1 migration

Ok. Then I clear db and up dump with two tables. Run migrations and have

1363786369.9579: SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='test'  => 1363786369.9597 (0.0018131732940674)
1363786369.9603: DESCRIBE `test`
  Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ff5.test' doesn't exist

Comment: First I make db - it's dump http://pastie.org/6649270

Then I make migrations - it's concat two file http://pastie.org/6649296

Then I make new table test - http://pastie.org/6649319

And generate migration - http://pastie.org/6649325

Then if I drop all tables and up first dump, and run migrations then I have error: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ff5.test' doesn't exist

Comment: I don't have personal experience with phalcon, but the migration is not accounting for any need to actually create the table.
You might need to look here instead - http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html#creating-altering-dropping-tables